# Simplying a Boolean Expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Hey everyone can anyone help me in simplifying the following boolean expression with explanation?

\begin{equation}[((p\land q)\implies r)\implies((q\land r')\implies r')]\land[(p \land q)\implies(q\iff p)]\end{equation}

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried simplying to DNF using the negation logic but seemingly it went wrong,

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: I saw that but what about the DNF form of the expression, what would that be? The best I got to by negation was (p v ~q v ~r) but it proved not to be a tautology thus being a wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the following table, the given statement is always true for any $p,q,r$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $(q\land r')\implies r'$ is always true. Thus first part of the statement becomes trivial.
Consider the statement $(p \land q)\implies(q\iff p)$. If $p=q=1$, it is true, otherwise it is vacuous. Hence, both parts of the to-be-simplified statement are always true and hence it is a tautology.